# Adding titles to loop graph R

Tags: r, loops, graph

Im trying to loop a lot of graphs in R. The code im using looks like this:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
#### Read data & Converting factors ####
dat <- read.table("Complete RING.txt", header =TRUE)  
str(dat)
dat$Vial <- as.factor(dat$Vial)
dat$Line <- as.factor(dat$Line)
dat$Fly <- as.factor(dat$Fly)  
dat$Temp <- as.factor(dat$Temp)
str(dat)


meltet <- melt(dat, id=c("Concentration","Sex","Line","Vial", "Fly", "Temp", "Vial_nr"))
meltet1 <- subset(meltet, Line=="20")
meltet1$variable <- as.factor(meltet1$variable)

AllConcentrations <- levels(unique(meltet1$Concentration))
for (i in AllConcentrations) {
meltet.i <- meltet1[meltet1$Concentration ==i,]
quartz()
print(dotplot(value~variable|Temp, group=Sex, data = meltet.i ,xlab="Time", ylab="Fly position", main=paste("Line 20 concentraion", AllConcentrations[i]))) }
```

The concentrations im using are denoted A, B, C, D, E, X and Y - how do i add a title to the plot that changes with the plots, i have tried to use the main=" " function but then i get the same name in each graph. The title i get now is: Line 20 concentration NA in each graph

EDIT: 
updated the code

Comment: Your code uses the same data.frame in each iteration of the loop. Add main = Concentration[1] to get the title

Comment: I have tried that, but i still get the same title on each plot..

Comment: I recommend using `as.is=TRUE` in your read.table() function. This forces R to read in character variables as characters. Since your code converts many of these explicitly, this will give you a chance to inspect the data in  a "raw" form after reading it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the AllConcentrations vector which you are looping through is a of class "character." If you want to use this in your title, use `main=AllConcentrations[i]`. You can also make this fancier with the paste function: `main=paste("Graph of", AllConcentrations[i])`.

Comment: Try looking at the contents of AllConcentrations to see if it varies. The graphing line `print(dotplot(value~variable|Temp, group=Line ,data = meltet1))` should be `print(dotplot(value~variable|Temp, group=Line ,data = meltet.i, main=AllConcentrations[i]))`

Comment: Using dotchart dosent work, i have also removed unique(), still i get a title saying NA

Comment: what are the contents of allContentrations?

Comment: chr [1:7] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "x" "y"

Comment: Add the following above the print line and see if it prints correctly: `print(paste("Line 20 concentraion", AllConcentrations[i]))`

Comment: It just prints this 7 times: [1] "Line 20 concentraion NA"

Comment: > print(AllConcentrations[i])
[1] NA

Comment: what about typing `AllConcentrations[1]` in the console?

Comment: > AllConcentrations
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "x" "y"

Comment: Aha. For some reason, AllConcentrations is a list of size 1. The following will work `AllConcentrations[1][i]` when used in the loop. Alternatively, you could use `AllConcentrations <- unlist(levels(meltet1$Concentration))` above the loop.

Comment: Still dosent change anything on my computer, i have also tried using: AllConcentrations[1] in the loop and then i get the Line 20 concentration a, but in all of them. Also changing the order of [i] and [1] has no effect

Comment: Nothing is working yet... i have tried moving the [] around but that doesn't work...